# if is_home(), change class of menu-item-225 of wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, menus, javascript

Thanks for taking the time to check this out. I know it's outdated, but I'm using Wordpress 3.2.1.

I have a Custom Home Page - where I created a Page for it and titled it as my Home Page with the custom URL.

I was hoping someone on here will know how to target the Custom page (whether by PHP, Javascript, etc), so that if it's on the home page, I can change the `menu-item-225` to have a class of `current_page_item`.

On my header.php, I have the following code.

```
if (is_home()) {
        wp_nav_menu(array('depth'=>0,'menu_class' => 'mainNavigation','container_id' => 'navwrap','menu'=>'Main Menu','link_before'=>'<span class="navspanFront">','link_after'=>'</span>'));                   
        }
        else {
            wp_nav_menu(array('depth'=>0,'menu_class' => 'mainNavigation','container_id' => 'navwrap','menu'=>'Main Menu','link_before'=>'<span class="navspanFront">','link_after'=>'</span>'));                   
        }
```

Comment: You know that the support idea behind WP is only supporting the _current_ version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding a class, just add a second selector to your `.current_menu_item` style of `.home .menu-item-225`. Not ideal, but for a single case, I think it's completely appropriate.

(This assumes that you're using `body_class()` on your `<body>` element, but you should be doing that anyway.)

Comment: Thank you so much mrwweb - I didn't think about doing it this way.